# Нужна помощь в верстке, проблема с навигацией

Tags: html, css

Всем доброго времени суток. Только недавно начал верстать. Пользуюсь справочниками по HTML и CSS. Я привык сам разбираться в проблемах, но не могу решить её, поэтому обращаюсь к вам. 
Дело вот в чем, я хотел сделать шапку , в которой был бы логотип + меню, вот пример:

[image: Пример - шапка]

Вместо белого квадрата - логотип, но логотип сделан не с помощью изображения, а с помощью стилей CSS.
Собственно, в чем проблема. Проблема заключается в том, что когда я размещаю меню, она съезжает вниз :

[image: Пример - Меню которое съезжает]

Решил использовать следующее свойство для стиля : `margin: -65px;`
Получилось.

И вот такой вопрос, как все таки сделать меню, чтобы не использовать данное свойство, и оно стояло как надо? И в чем может быть проблема?

HTML код:

```css
header {
  background: url('/img/sea-water.jpg');
  background-origin: content-box;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
}

.header-menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(51, 75, 95,0.90);
}

.header-informer {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.header-informer p {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-top: 200px;
  text-shadow:  1px 1px 0 black, 1px 1px 0 black,1px 1px 0 black;
}

.header-informer mark {
  background: white;
  padding: .2em;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.navigation ul {
  list-style: none; 
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.navigation a {
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: .5s linear;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
nav {
  display: block;
  margin: -65px;

}
.navigation ul {
  padding-left: 850px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
.navigation a {
  padding: 40px;
}
.navigation a:hover {background: #5881a3;}
.navigation li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header-menu">
    <h2 class="logo">ТекстА<span class="logotext">ТекстБ</span></h2>
    <nav class="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Блог</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Войти</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="header-informer">
    <p>ТекстА<span class="logotext p">ТекстБ</span> - Текст текст текст</p>
    <mark>Мир</mark> лучше, чем <mark>Война</mark>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Покажите пример кода для наглядности и информативности

Comment: Точно, спасибо! Сейчас сделаю!

Answer (score 1):

Это пример , как меню выглядит на десктопе и как оно складывается в квадратик , кликабельно

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button").click(function() {
    $(".menu").toggleClass("main");
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clear,
.clear:after,
.clear:before {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

section {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 80px;
  background: #f7f5f5;
}

.brand {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 80px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.menu {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
}

.menu li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:620px) {
  section {
    position: relative;
  }
  .menu {
    width: 230px;
    background: #f7f5f5;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: -10px;
    top: 100%;
  }
  .menu li {
    float: none;
    clear: all;
    display: block;
    line-height: 40px;
  }
  .button {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    float: right;
    margin: 20px;
  }
  .button span {
    display: block;
    width: 36px;
    height: 6px;
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 5px auto;
  }
  .main {
    overflow: auto;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<section class="clear">
  <div class="brand">
    <img src="http://lazer-beauty.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/logotip.png">
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="">Главная</a>
      <li><a href="">Блог</a>
        <li><a href="">Войти</a>
  </ul>
</section>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Пример в песочнице : https://codepen.io/simkaUser/pen/ZyRzPw
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, пригодится )

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так, думаю сможете использовать со своим кодом.

```css
.header-wrap{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.left-logo{
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;   
}
```

```html
<div class="header-wrap">
  <a href="#" class="left-logo"></a>
  <ul class="right-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Вроде как получается, спасибо :)

Comment: @NeroKore Советую изучить материал http://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

Задать ширину и `float: left` логотипу, и так же навигации.

```css
header {
  background: url('/img/sea-water.jpg');
  background-origin: content-box;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

.header-menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(51, 75, 95,0.90);
}

.header-informer {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.header-informer p {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-top: 200px;
  text-shadow:  1px 1px 0 black, 1px 1px 0 black,1px 1px 0 black;
}

.header-informer mark {
  background: white;
  padding: .2em;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.navigation ul {
  list-style: none; 
  margin: 0;
  text-align: right;
  /* position: absolute; */
}

.navigation a {
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: .5s linear;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

nav {
  display: block;
  width: 75%;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
}

.navigation ul {
 /*  padding-left: 850px; */
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
.navigation a {
  padding: 40px;
  display: block;
}
.navigation a:hover {background: #5881a3;}
.navigation li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header-menu">
    <h2 class="logo">ТекстА<span class="logotext">ТекстБ</span></h2>
    <nav class="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Блог</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Войти</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="header-informer">
    <p>ТекстА<span class="logotext p">ТекстБ</span> - Текст текст текст</p>
    <mark>Мир</mark> лучше, чем <mark>Война</mark>
  </div>
</header>
```

Есть варианты с флекс.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую